# Installing KDE 5 in Linux mint 17.3

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kde-plasma-5

I have been trying to install KDE 5 on linux mint 17.3 Rosa

I know I need to add a PPA to do this first, I have been trying both

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neon/kf5
```

and

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neon/ppa
```

both give me a message though saying they cant be added because 
''This PPA does not support trusty''

However I should be running Rosa 17.3 according to
 /etc/linuxmint/info

Is there another way i can add the PPA or install KDE 5?
Thanks

Comment: Linux Mint 17.3 is based on Ubuntu 14.04 `Trusty` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_Mint_releases

Answer (score 0):

---

Install kde 5 on ubuntu 14.04 https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=install+kde+5+on+ubuntu+14.04

---

Comment: link only answer are frown upon, can you post revelent part of link ?